# The noun acting as adjective

Tags: nouns, semantics

Sometimes a noun can describe another noun (ex. mountain bike), usually adjectives are used to describe a noun. But there is also a possibility to create an adjective from the noun.

What makes that sometimes it is valid to use a noun instead of adjective (even this which was derived from the noun) ? Why we say for example "golden bridge" instead of "gold bidge", what is the difference ?

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct  Good Luck. "Dawlish pub car park cliff plunge man rescued"

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please see also [ell.se].

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It needs thinking about.  The practice of placing nouns in an adjectival position and role is not as new as it seems.  'egg nog', 'Easter egg', 'Christmas tree', 'board meeting', 'chain mail', 'post box'...  This is not a new phenomenon.  What has occurred is an explosion in the extent of such uses.

Comment: A golden bridge would be painted gold, a gold one would be made of gold!

Comment: Whereas a *goldbrick* is something else entirely.

Comment: It is not "acting like an adjective".  [Using nouns attributively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributive-nouns?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) creates a compound noun, not an adjective plus a noun. The properties are entirely different.

Comment: @tchrist - Unfortunately, there several different nomenclatures used for such situations, most obscuring rather than clarifying the sentence structure.  Saying "acting like an adjective" is a perfectly valid way to explain it, and one that is far easier for the uninitiated to comprehend.

Answer (score -2):

It is called compound nouns (which is a compound noun itself), a compound variation that is open. Such a construct consists of one noun and an attributive noun or an adjective. In this case it would be: one noun and an attributive noun (which acts as if it was an adjective). 
Reference: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012
Did you mean: "Golden Gate Bridge"? In this case, it is a proper noun, based on the name of the bay "Golden Gate". Otherwise, and as mentioned before, "golden bridge" would be a bridge made of gold, partially made of gold or would have an appearance of gold to it. "Gold Bridge" might be a proper noun.

Comment: "Compound" can be a noun, an adjective, or a verb.  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compound)

Comment: Thank you. It is a "compound noun" - not solely a "compound". It is not possible to use a verb in this type of word. 
Would be nice, if those who downvote, at least, left a comment.